# Identity method factory in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Is there a shortcut in Ruby to receive a lambda which simply returns its argument?

I'm trying to have the following function:

```rb
def some_method(x, y, decorator = ->(x) { x })
  …
end
```

Rewritten to look somehow like

```rb
def some_method(x, y, decorator = method(:itself))
  …
end
```

Maybe there's a way to change the receiver with `Object#itself`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have probably seen code like this plenty of times in ruby:

```
array.map(&:upcase)
```

Well, what does `&:upcase` actually mean? It's actually calling [`Symbol#to_proc`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Symbol.html#method-i-to_proc).

Therefore, you could choose to define the method like this:

```
def some_method(x, y, decorator = :itself.to_proc)
  # ...
end
```